# Having one thread running per enum component

Tags: java, multithreading, enums

As the title, I have a class with a list of enums and in that class I have a method newOpponent which creates the thread I would want to only have 1 thread of one enum type running at the time.

I store a hashmap with threads corresponding to my enums;

What I'm trying to do and is not working is to when specific condition is met call my method destroyOpponent(type) (from thread) and this method removes thread from that hashmap and also changes the while condition that was in thread's run() method so now it will be false and calls again newOpponent (to create a new one on place of this one) the thread should finish the method and end and the new one should be created.

The thread never actually finishes so I get multiple running later on at once with unexpected results.

```
public class GameOpponents {

    Radar radar;
    Poi player;
    public enum Type{
        rocket
    }

    Map<Type, Poi> OpponentsMap = new HashMap();
    Map<Type, Thread> OpponentsThreadMap = new HashMap();

 public void newOpponent(){
        Type type = Type.rocket;

        Poi opponent = randomLocationOpponent(type);
        OpponentsMap.put(type, opponent);
        radar.addPoi(OpponentsMap.get(type));

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                double[] XYSpeed = getXYSpeedTowardsPlayer(type);
                while(OpponentsMap.get(type)!=null){

                    moveOpponent(type, XYSpeed[0], XYSpeed[1]);
                    if(distanceToPlayer(OpponentsMap.get(type))>2) destroyOpponent(type);
                    try {
                        sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GameOpponents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if(thread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW){
            OpponentsThreadMap.put(type, thread);
            OpponentsThreadMap.get(type).start();
        }
        else if(OpponentsThreadMap.get(type).getState()==Thread.State.TERMINATED){
            System.out.println("TERMINATED");
            OpponentsThreadMap.replace(type, thread);
            OpponentsThreadMap.get(type).start();
        }

    }

    private void destroyOpponent(Type type){
        radar.removePoi(OpponentsMap.get(type));
        OpponentsMap.remove(type);
        OpponentsThreadMap.remove(type);
        newOpponent();
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you modifying your map from multiple threads? That usually doesn't end well. Also if you almost certainly don't need threads for this at all.

Comment: @pvg how can I achieve waiting for each object for x seconds without stoping the main thread which would stop the whole program? I'm adding to the map from the main thread and removing from those individual threads

Comment: I agree with @pvg, You shouldn't have to use all these kludges that you're using.  Is this a GUI? Is it written in an event-driven way?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, all gui changes are done on EDT /invokelater

Comment: condition thread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW is always true since thread is just created.